# How to keep x-axis in fixed position while scrolling using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 matrix, with an x and y-axis. My y-axis is pretty long, so I want to be able to still see my x axis when I scroll. I want to have the position 'fixed.' But adding .style("position", "fixed") doesn't seem to do the trick. In simple terms, I want to do what excel does when it freezes a row/column.

Code I have:

```
  var columnLabels = svg.append("g")
  .selectAll(".columnLabelg")
  .data(columnLabel)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d; })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * cellSize; })
  .attr("y", -1)
  .style("text-anchor", "right")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
      return "translate(" + i + ",-6)"
             + "rotate(300 "+ i * cellSize + " " + (-6) +")"; })


  .attr("class",  function (d,i) { return "columnLabel mono c"+i;} )
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {d3.select(this).classed("text-hover",true);})
  .on("mouseout" , function(d) {d3.select(this).classed("text-hover",false);}) 
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be to create a header div which would then be made sticky at the top of the screen throughout scroll. You can display whatever you like in it, keep it sticky, and scroll through the rest of your matrix normally if you use something like scrollmagic, which requires a bit of additional JavaScript.

For example, if you create a container div, add the column labels inside, and pin that to the top of the screen, things should work.

For example:

```js
var labelContainer = d3.select("div.label-container")

//Let's pretend that you've create the labels thus:
var columnLabels = labelContainer
  .selectAll(".columnLabel")
  .data(columnLabel)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "label")


//Now let's create a scrollmagic scene, the duration of which will let you set the length during which the element is sticky on scroll.

var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

$(function() { // wait for document ready

  // build scene
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#trigger1",
      duration: 300
    })
    .setPin("#pin1")
    .addIndicators({
      name: "1 (duration: 300)"
    }) // add indicators (requires plugin)
    .addTo(controller);
});
```

```html
<div id="trigger1" class="label-container">

  <div class="label"></div>
  <div class="label"></div>

</div>
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg class="svg-viz"></svg>
</div>
```

That said, in addition to loading d3, you'd want to load the Scrollmagic and jquery libraries:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you may want to add indicators to show you where your scene starts and ends using the following scrollmagic library:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
```

You can read a little more about scrollmagic pinning here: http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html